# "xxx does not named a type" error in OpenCV program

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I am coding an computer vision program using OpenCV library. In my program, I "typedef" a type called "CLabPixelType" by "Vec3d", which is to represent a color pixel in Lab color space. However, I encounter the following problem when I compile the code by g++ under Mac OS X Mountain Lion with XCode 4.4.1.

```
g++ ${CXXFLAGS} main.cpp slic.cpp slic_contrast.cpp -o sclbp -I/opt/local/include 
-L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_core.2.4.2 -lopencv_imgproc.2.4.2 -lopencv_highgui.2.4.2

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/map.h:59,
             from lxp_factory.h:8,
             from cmd_parser.h:4,
             from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This 
file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please consider using 
one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples 
include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ includes, or
<iostream> instead of the deprecated header     >>><iostream.h>. To disable this
warning use -Wno-deprecated.

In file included from lxp_framework.h:5,
             from lxp_factory.h:5,
             from cmd_parser.h:4,
             from main.cpp:2:
img_interpolater.h:10: error: ‘Vec3d’ does not name a type
img_interpolater.h:45: error: ‘CLabPixelType’ does not name a type
img_interpolater.h:97: error: ‘CLabPixelType’ does not name a type
```

I do not know why it shows "'Vec3d' does not name a type? I checked the other questions about such "XX does not name a type" error in Stackoverflow but failed to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a while back when I used opencv library the last time, but I think the problem may be that you don't take into account [namespace cv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/namespace_%5Ctexttt%7Bcv%7D_and_function_naming.html)

Try adding `using namespace cv`, or `using namespace cv::CLabPixelType` or just qualify the name fully each time you use it like `typedef cv::CLabPixelType Vec3d`.